# check if data already exist inside mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, database

i am new in PHP so i am struggling to solve this issue.

here is my code which stores the variable values in specific table rows inside the table "booked".

i want to make sure mysql rejects the insertion of the value inside the database table "booked" if all the variable values already exist inside the database.

note: all the values have to be identical to be rejected. for example: if all the values are identical except for one value, the system should still accept the insertion.

the code i wrote below first checks if the data is already present inside the database. if it is present it echos "data already exists", if not then it inserts the new value inside the database.

however this code doesn't seem to work, so i was wondering if you guys could check my code to see what i am doing wrong?

```
     <?php

        $servername = "localhost";
        $name = "root";
        $password = "root";
        $dbname = "my computer";

        // Create connection
        $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $name, $password, $dbname);
        // Check connection
        if (!$conn) {
           die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
        }



        $query = "SELECT * FROM `booked` WHERE 

        `name` = '{$username}'
        `date` = '{$date}'
        `computer_id` = '{$select3}'
        `start_time` = '{$select1}'
        `end_time` = '{$select2}'
        `room` = '{$room}'

        ";

        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);



        if ( mysqli_num_rows ( $result ) > 1 )
        {

        echo "data already exists";

        }




        else
        {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO booked (date, computer_id, name, start_time, end_time, room)
            VALUES ('$date', '$select3', '$username', '$select1', '$select2', '$room')";



        if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
           echo "New record created successfully";
            } else {
           echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
            }

        mysqli_close($conn);

        }
        ?>
```

Comment: where are all those variables coming from here?

Comment: you didn't tell us what syntax error you got here. It's pretty obvious you didn't read the manual on SELECT and the WHERE clause.

Comment: Hopefully this isn't depending on register_globals to populate all those variables.

Comment: oh that's right; you didn't check for errors on the one that's failing; *my bad*. You just assumed it's going to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your forgot to put `AND` keyword inside SQL query. Update your query like this,

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `booked` WHERE 
        `name` = '{$username}' AND 
        `date` = '{$date}' AND 
        `computer_id` = '{$select3}' AND 
        `start_time` = '{$select1}' AND 
        `end_time` = '{$select2}' AND 
        `room` = '{$room}'
        ";
```

We used `AND` here to match all the conditions, if all the conditions are matched only then it will return result.

There is another keyword called `OR` which is also used in `WHERE` clause. If `OR` is applied within two conditions (`WHERE column1=1 OR column2=2`) either of the condition should match to get the results.

You can also use mix of `AND` and `OR`.
**Reference:** http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/logical-operators.html

Comment: Although you're right about this, that would mean that all conditions must be met. If they're trying to check for partials, then they'd need an `OR`, or a mix of, or a sub-query.

Comment: True, added content of `OR` too.

Comment: hi, sorry i didn't know i had to do that, im new here... i will do that for all my questions from now on

Answer (score 0):

First try adding AND after every condition to your query, this AND operator will make your condition readable to sql for multiple conditions, operators also separates or combines every conditions of a query. Now you need to add AND not OR because you need to check for all the columns if it is existed.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `booked` WHERE 

    `name` = '{$username}' AND
    `date` = '{$date}' AND
    `computer_id` = '{$select3}' AND
    `start_time` = '{$select1}' AND
    `end_time` = '{$select2}' AND
    `room` = '{$room}'

    ";
```

if the code above will not work then try this one. Make it one line to avoid white spaces and remove the single quote ' to every column name or table name to make it readable to sql.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM booked WHERE name = '{$username}' AND date = '{$date}' AND computer_id = '{$select3}' AND start_time = '{$select1}' AND end_time = '{$select2}' AND room = '{$room}'";
```

Comment: care to tell us all "why"? all you did was pop in code.

Comment: The question is why he has error the query and the reason I think was because he forgot to add operator(AND,OR) after a new condition. as stated by @Alok (first answer)

Comment: a good answer has an explanation of the suggested code in the answer, and not as a comment below, after someone has to ask "why"

Comment: sorry, I will edit my main answer above with explanation of what I've understand.

Answer (score -2):

in your line: if ( mysqli_num_rows ( $result ) > 1 )

try adding equal sign on it. so it should be

if ( mysqli_num_rows ( $result ) >= 1 )

Comment: that isn't what the problem is.